# Setup a Laravel 5 application to be used in multiple modes

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-5

We are developing an application in Laravel 5 where users can login and based on the licenses assigned to the user, multiple "content types" are available within the app. The business logic and presentation logic differs based on the selected content type. The user can select the content type to work with, or, if only one license is available, will be directed to the homepage of that content type.

Now I am trying to figure out how to handle the selected content type. Storing this in a session is imo not the way to go because a user must be able to use multiple content types in one browser session simultaneously.

I figured I need to start with grouping all relevant routes and prefixes them with {contentType}. Also, add a Middleware (named something like SelectContentTypeMiddleware) and let that middleware check if the content type exists, and if the logged in user is allowed to have access to it.

Furthermore, every descending route (in the {contentType} prefix route group) also must handle the route parameter $contentType.

I am trying to figure out of this is the right approach. I was looking at this [blogpost](https://blog.hernandev.com/en/testing-laravel-5-middlewares) which addresses the case for setting the app locale. Using app()->setLocale($locale) the locale for that request is set. I was wondering if a similar approach for my case makes sense, or that including the route parameter $contentType in every route is more advisable.

Comment: what do you mean by "content types" ?

Comment: The mode where the application is in. For example the application contains multiple online games, each game had different rules, but some overlap exists.